# Pip3 for Python3 in virtual environment not installing package according to path

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install packages in a Python3 virtual environment using pip3. Pip3 is pointing to the virtual environment when it is active.

Packages will not install, since they are installed outside of the virtual environment, already satisfied outside of the virtual environment.

How do I install packages in the virtual environment?

And how can I be sure that I am actually using the interpreter inside the virtual environment? When pip3 is not acting according to the location returned by 'which', I do can not be sure that the python I am using in fact is the one from the virtual environment.

```
(venv_name) user_name@user_name-ubuntu:/mnt/ramdisk$ which python3
/mnt/ramdisk/venv_name/bin/python3
```

---

```
(venv_name) user_name@name-ubuntu:/mnt/ramdisk$ which pip3
/mnt/ramdisk/venv_name/bin/pip3
```

---

```
(venv_name) user_name@name-ubuntu:/mnt/ramdisk$ sudo pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages ...
```

---

```
(venv_name) user_name@name-ubuntu:/mnt/ramdisk$ python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 15 2019, 22:40:07) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

---

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

OS: UBUNTU 18.04

Comment: Do not use `sudo` with `pip install`! Do not use `sudo` with virtual environments!! `sudo pip install` runs **outside** of virtualenv!!!

Comment: Yes, that worked. I was not aware that sudo run outside of virtualenv. I used sudo with pip as I needed the privileges to write to the folder. I solved this by changing the folder location. I believe I also could have solved it by changing the restrictions on the folder.

Comment: There are probably ways to ensure `sudo` will use the virtual environment, but as long as you are creating a virtual environment, you may as well ensure you can access it without `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by not using sudo. Sudo was used for access.